# Vue - Unable to render component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Some components cannot be injected into the App.vue template. Particularly, the `Login.vue` is the one that is causing issues. If I create it from scratch while the server is running (`npm run dev`) it will work, but once I restart it and navigate to the Login component, it will fail to load.

**Stack Trace**

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <Login>
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
```

**src/components/Login.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="login">
    <ul>
      <li><input type="text" v-model="username" placeholder="Username"></li>
      <li><input type="password" v-model="password" placeholder="Password"></li>
      <li><button @click="login(username, password)">Login</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
</script>

<style scoped>

#login{
  padding-top: 100px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

</style>
```

**src/router/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Hello from '@/components/Hello'
import RideSharing from '@/components/RideSharing'
import Login from '@/components/Login'
import About from '@/components/About'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Hello',
      component: Hello
    },
    {
      path: '/app',
      name: 'RideSharing',
      component: RideSharing
    },
    {
      path: '/app/login',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login
    },
    {
      path: '/app/about',
      name: 'About',
      component: About
    }
  ]
})
```

**src/App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app" :style="{padding: $route.path === '/' ? '172px' : '10px'}">
    <div>
      <img src="./assets/logo4.png" align="center">
    </div>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app'
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: hsla(269, 96%, 50%, 0.73);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 0px;
  height: inherit;
}

body{
  height: inherit;
}

html{
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

**src/main.js**

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import BootstrapVue from "bootstrap-vue"
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

Comment: can you share the login.js file?

Comment: Shouldn't the Login component be contained in the App?

Comment: Then why do you have: <script src="./login.js">? That would suggest an outside file login.js.

Comment: @Efrat Sorry, I forgot to omit that part. The login.js file was empty and wasn’t the source of the issue.

Comment: @Jayem163 script pointer shouldn’t have been there. Edited the code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the full build version of Vue then you could try to mount the DOM template using `.$mount('#app')`

So, in your main.js, your app script would look like this:

```
new Vue({
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App },
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

Missing `.vue` extensions in imports.

**src/router/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Hello from '@/components/Hello.vue'
import RideSharing from '@/components/RideSharing.vue'
import Login from '@/components/Login.vue'
import About from '@/components/About.vue'
```